# Pyspark How to Ignore Double quotes from the data present in the CSV files

Tags: csv, pyspark, delimiter

I am having " (single quotes) in my data ,all the corresponding column values clubbed into one column even though I have used the delimiter value. In my case '|' is my delimiter.

**Actual Data:**

a|"b|c|d|

**Expected Output:**

a|"b|c|d

**Actual Output Came:**

a|"b**|c|d|**null|null|  ( here 3rd & 4th column coming as single column, in place of actual 3rd & 4th col.. getting values as null)

I have tried below approach:

**Approach 1:**

```
df=spark.read.csv(filepath,header=True,sep='|',quote='')
```

Above approach gives particular column data correctly but empty columns coming values as """" but we need empty column as it is.

**Approach 2:**

```
df=spark.read.csv(filepath,header=True,sep='|',quote='',escape='\"')
```

Above approach gives values clubbing into single column as like actual output.

Answer (score 1):

After some heads & trails

found solution

read the file with both below options :

```
quote='',escape='\"'
```